# SQL Insert date/time & acquired value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sql, asp-classic, ado

I am trying to insert current date/time and a value that was redirected to this errorpage  into an access database.  So far the only issue is coming from when i add the redirected value into the insert statement. Here is my code.

```
errnum = Request.QueryString("errnum")
prevPageTitle = request.querystring("pagetitle")

Function AccessDateTime (dateandtime)
Dim myDay
Dim myMonth
Dim myYear

myDay = Day(dateandtime)
If Len(myDay)=1 Then myDay="0" & myDay

myMonth = Month(dateandtime)
If Len(myMonth)=1 Then myMonth="0" & myMonth

myYear = Year(dateandtime)

AccessDateTime = myYear & "-" & myMonth & "-" & myDay & " " & Time()
End Function

Dim connection
Dim SQL, sConnString

SQL="INSERT INTO ErrorTable (ErrorTime, ErrorPage) VALUES (#" & AccessDateTime(NOW()) & "#, #" & prevPageTitle & "#)"   
//////This is where the issue is, ErrorPage column isn't updated with prevPageTitle acquired information. 

(Error Type:
Microsoft JET Database Engine (0x80040E07)
Syntax error in date in query expression '#Pre-ErrorPage.asp#'.//////

sConnString="PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
"Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("ErrorTimeLog.mdb")
Set connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
connection.Open(sConnString)
connection.execute(SQL)

Connection.Close
Set Connection = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone needs an answer to a similar question. The issue was in the syntax of my SQL statement.

```
SQL="INSERT INTO ErrorTable (ErrorTime,ErrorPage,ErrorNumber) VALUES (#" & AccessDateTime(NOW()) & "#, '" & prevPageTitle & "', '" & errnum & "')"
```

Single quotes were needed around the acquired variables.